# Permission denied -unable to execute remote ssh commands

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins running on my Unix Box and i am invoking a script from remote server . I trying to figure out remote ssh problem I'm having on a server. I'm getting this permission denied error which indicates a problem with the key, yet from the same user account on the shell, I can definitely connect to my remote machine and execute the .sh file .I see the following error on the logs .

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).

I tried using -t -t and -vv options and then i just see 
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password) .

.ssh permisssions are 700 and file permissions are 644

Do i have to create ssh keys for my Jenkins user on host and transfer it to remote server ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use *Key-Based Authentication*: `ssh` will look by default in `$HOME\.ssh\` for aviable identities for authentication. Are you sure you tested the remote execution logged in as user `jenkins`?

You can also use the option `-i` to provide ssh a custom identity file location.